# CSS percentage width and margin questions (using bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, margin

I'm realizing a sort of "mobile responsive first web design" using twitter Bootstrap 3 and I have some issues on margins and  resizing.

My intent is to realize what I described already in my previous question:
[mobile first responsive web design and responsive images questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24587434/1786393)

The site is an ecommerce showing a list of products and each product is a panel. 
In HTML terms: each panel is a  containing a square  that fullfill the . 
all in all each page is a sequence of .

BTW, application is online: http://rosposhop.herokuapp.com

ISSUES:
On a mobile phone in landscape mode, I would like to visualize two columns, I mean two   side by side instead of one as in portrait mode.

To do that I used CSS Media queries; here an excerpt of rosposhop.css (the application CSS definitions file):

```
 /* product box (containing image) */
    .pb {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
   }

    /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .pb {width:100.0%;}
    }

    /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
   @media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation: landscape) {
   .pb {width:49.718572%;}
   }
```

As you see, my naive idea is to modify the width of each  according with the current viewport, so by example in landscape mode let the width decrease from 100% to 50%.

BUT I have anyway some pixels of separation between each ; that's why I tempt a "long" fractional value:

```
.pb {width:49.718572%;}
```

Here a screenshot:

[image]

Issues are shown with reference numbers in photo:

**(1) viewport left margin and (2) viewport right margin**

My intent was to fulfill the vieport space, avoiding any margin (sort of full-screen mode)
but  instead I have these unwanted 1 pixel margin on the left and the right.
Maybe the problem is in the percentage setting, that do not calculate perfectly the presence of margin separtion between the divs (see point 3)

I also tryied, without success, to remove pixels with the CSS calc directive:

```
.pb {width:calc(50% - 3px);
```

Any idea to remove these 1 pixel margins ?

**(3) "orizontal" pixels gap between divs and (4) "vertical" pixels gap between divs**

That's another problem. Reminding I'm using bootstrap 3, How can I set the gap (3) to be less than ... (3?) pixels, by example how can I set that gap to 1 pixel ?

Sorry in advance for my ignorance on CSS... I'm a backend man instead

giorgio

Comment: The vertical gap (4) comes from the elements being displayed as `inline-block` – to fix it, set `vertical-align:top` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The body has a set line height that is one of the gap reasons: line-height: 1.42857;

Also remove the display: inline-block; and use position: relative; float: left; instead :)

That does however remove your left margin, so if you want to keep that you will need to wrap all the elements in a div and set margin: 0 auto; with position: relative;

Hope this helps a tiny bit, and good luck!

Comment: Yes: body{line-height:1;} bring "horizontal" gaps to 1 pixel :-) still I see that "vertical" gaps betweens <div> seem relative to viewport resolution; by example on a smartphone it seem 1 pixel, whereas on a pc it seem 2/3 px. Instead following your other suggestion create some collateral effects... anyway thank you!

Comment: All right! No problem and again good luck! Just give a shout out if you need any more help :)